# Vue dev tool display only <root>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, google-chrome-devtools, vue-devtools

i often see only <root> tag in components in vue devtool. If i search a specific component in page, it display like you see on picture below right sight. When i reload page a few times it appears all the tree but in next reload it disappear again.
I'm performing this issue for Vue dev tool for all browser. (chrome, firefox, and edge)
Vue3 + Pinia + vueX

[image: Edge Dev tool]

Comment: Got the same issue if using Chrome?

Comment: Are you naming your components? With a `name` inside the default export ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV that should still have a fallback even if omitted.

Comment: Maybe Pinia and Vuex are mutually incompatible? Or maybe there is a bug in Vue DevTools. Try opening and closing the DevTools a couple of times - it might reset.

Comment: @kissu Yes it does. Same problem with chrome also.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Each component has a unique name, as you see on right side, my component is called as field-contaniner

Comment: Probably deserves filing a bug report on their GitHub repo.

Comment: Gonna need a [repro] tho, as of right now it's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the case why i got this error. I'm using aggrid in my project. When aggrid launched in the page, i can't see my components in vue dev tool. But in any other page it works properly.
I think aggrid lance another instance of vue. I don't have any solution but found the case :)